# Exposing WSO2 ESB as REST for use in JavaScript

Tags: wso2, esb

I have been digging around in Stackoverflow and WSO2 ESB documentation for days but I have yet to come across any clear answer.

My application is in JavaScript and using the Dojo framework. Ideally all the web services call should be make against REST and returns JSON. I know how to get the SOAP xml to come back as JSON because of this example 440: "**http//wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample440**"  I have looked at the sample posted on this blog as well: "**http//vvratha.blogspot.ca/2011/11/invoking-restful-service-via-wso2esb.html**"  I seems to be able to call the proxy service from tools like soapUI and get my result in JSON. So I can only assume that ESB is working properly **However when I try to call it using dojo.xhrGet or dojo.io.script.get, the data returns as NULL always!!!**

What is the method in REST am I supposed to call for a ESB Proxy Service? If I look at the wsdl of the service, the operation seems to call "mediate" but that did not get me any further. I have looked at example 800: "**http//wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/rest_api_samples.html#Sample800**"   but I am not clear where to use this.

Note: Please add ":" after http for those http links. I seems to be running out of quotas for hyperlinks.

More information after some help from Ratha:
1. This is how I want to call the proxy service: (There will be more querystring parameters later)
http//loh7:8280/services/TestRestProxy?address=1460%20nicholson%20road

1. Query string is null from this Mediation Message Tracker dump:

   13:10:10,803 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Proxy Service TestRestProxy received a new message from : 192.168.7.143
   13:10:10,803 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Message To: /services/TestRestProxy?address=1460%20nicholson%20road
   13:10:10,803 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO SOAPAction: null
   13:10:10,803 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO WSA-Action: null
   13:10:10,803 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Using the anonymous in-sequence of the proxy service for mediation
   13:10:10,804 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Start : Sequence 
   13:10:10,804 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Sequence  :: mediate()
   13:10:10,804 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Start : Log mediator
   13:10:10,805 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO querystring = null
   13:10:10,805 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO End : Log mediator
   13:10:10,806 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Start : Log mediator
   13:10:10,806 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO End : Log mediator
   13:10:10,806 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Start : Send mediator
   13:10:10,806 [-] [HttpServerWorker-16] INFO Sending message through endpoint : EsriNA10 resolving to address =

This is how the proxy looks like:
Note: I wanted to extract the "address" value and put it in the $1 in the request soap message.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestRestProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="querystring" expression="get-property('REST_URL_POSTFIX')" />
         </log>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <GeocodeAddress xmlns="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                  <Address xmlns="">
                     <PropertyArray>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>Street</Key>
                           <Value>$1</Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>City</Key>
                           <Value>Newmarket</Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>State</Key>
                           <Value>ON</Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>Zip</Key>
                           <Value>L3Y 9C3</Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>Country</Key>
                           <Value>CANADA</Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                     </PropertyArray>
                  </Address>
                  <PropMods xmlns="">
                     <PropertyArray>
                        <PropertySetProperty>
                           <Key>OutputSpatialReference</Key>
                           <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0" xsi:type="q2:ProjectedCoordinateSystem">
                              <WKID>102100</WKID>
                           </Value>
                        </PropertySetProperty>
                     </PropertyArray>
                  </PropMods>
               </GeocodeAddress>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="$ctx:querystring" />
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full" category="TRACE" separator="," />
         <send>
            <endpoint key="EsriNA10" />
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="," />
         <xslt key="out_transform" />
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sample 800 it explains how you can directly invoke RESTAPIs..
For example, if you have your REST service endpoints point that as your service endpoint. Note that the following configuration;

```
<api name="StockQuoteAPI" context="/stockquote">
   <resource uri-template="/view/{symbol}" methods="GET">
```

Where we define the RESTAPI call stockquoteAPI and defining the context and uritemplate..
So, when you try to execute above API, use curl or other REST client and execute like;

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/view/IBM
```

Here you will see we provide the context and uri template..from that we pick symbol call IBM and sending to stcokquote service..But it is your logic, you can define your own logic in the sequence.

**Edit**

From browser try like this;

```
http://localhost:8280/services/yourProxy/<Operation>?param1=21312&param2=wqeqw
```

Here the "operation" is the operation(which is present at your backend REST service) you try to invoke.

"Mediate" is the default operation..If you want to execute your actual backend service operation provide that operation as i mentioned above.

When you define proxy follow my sample in the blog..

```
<proxy name="yourProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>   
            <endpoint>
              <address uri="Your REST SERVICE ENDPOINT URL"/>
            </endpoint>  
           <inSequenc>
               <log level ="custom">
                 <property name="querystrings" expression=get-property('REST_URL_POSTFIX')/>
               </log>
          </inSequnece>           
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Try above proxy and see what it logs fro "querystrings"

Comment: Then I guess sample 800 is not what I should be looking at since I want to call an ESB proxy service as an REST service and passing in the parameters as query strings. Essentially I want to be able to type something like this in the browser: "http://127.0.0.1:[port]/MyService/[ServiceMethod]?param1=1232&param2=aaabbb&param3=123211" This is the way (as I understand it) if the ESB service is exposed as a REST service. What kind of proxy service in ESB will allow me to do that? How can I get the query string parameters once I am in the ESB proxy service?

Comment: If you want to execute proxy from browser you can do that..This sample explains that.http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/11/invoking-restful-service-via-wso2esb.html

Comment: To get query strings use property mediator  <property name="querystrings" expression= get-property('REST_URL_POSTFIX')  and use log mediator to log and see

Comment: Thank you Ratha. Since I am new to WSO2, I need to know a bit more. If my TryIt url looks like this "http://loh7:8280/services/TestGeocodeWorldLocator", you are saying that I can put my querystring (?param1=21312&param2=wqeqw...) directly after and dig it out using "REST_URL_POSTFIX". What will be that property looks like? Suppose I only have 1, how can I get at it so I can replace a $1 in a payload factory?

Comment: If I am exposing a REST service from ESB, what is the "method" or "operation" that I am suppose to be accessing? All other REST service that I have accessed in the pass from JavaScript have some kind of method you need to call. If I look at the proxy service in the ESB server console, it seems like the method is called "mediate". Is this correct?

Comment: Check my previous answer ..i have edited..Hope that helps you

Comment: Querystring came up null. I put my proxy service in my edited question area so you can see what I am trying to do. That EsriNA10 endpoint is pointing a SOAP web service and the payload factory contains my request. Obviously I want to pass in my own values for address, city, state, etc. The JSON transformation is from sample 440 and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to invoke allt hese http verbs.Simply define what type of the verb you like to execute..and route the request to the service endpoint
This is a simple introduction part..hope may help you..
http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/09/rest-support-in-wso2esb-introduction.html